# Salvar Objeto no controller do outro objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma *classe* **Colaborador**, e uma *classe* **Endereco**.
o colaborador tem um endereço. Na minha classe colaborador eu tenho um:

```
 public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("Endereco")]
 public int? IdEndereco { get; set; }
```

Essa é minha view Create Colaborador:

```
 <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col col-md-2">
       <label for="text-input" class="form-control-label">Rua:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10" ;>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.EndRua, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "min-width:100%;", type = "text", id = "text-input", name = "text-input", placeholder = "Rua | Avenida" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.EndRua, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*<input style="min-width:100%;" type="text" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Rua | Avenida" class="form-control-sm">*@
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row form-group ">
    <div class="col col-md-2">
       <label for="email-input" class=" form-control-label">Número:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.EndNumero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "width:59px;", type = "text", id = "text-input", name = "text-input", placeholder = "N°" } })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.EndNumero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       @*<input style="width:59px;" type="text" id="numero-input" name="nascimento-input" placeholder="Número" class="form-control-sm">*@
    </div>

    <div class="offset-md-2">
       <div class="col col-md-2">
          <label for="cpf-input" class=" form-control-label">Bairro:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.EndBairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "margin-left:-2px; width:237px;", type = "email", id = "text-input", name = "text-input", placeholder = "Bairro" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.EndBairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          @*<input style="margin-left:-2px; width:237px;" type="text" id="bairro-input" name="bairro-input" placeholder="Bairro" class="form-control-sm">*@
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row form-group ">
       <div class="col col-md-2">
          <label for="complemento-input" class=" form-control-label">Complemento:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.EndComplemento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "width:270px;", type = "text", id = "text-input", name = "text-input", placeholder = "Complemento" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.EndComplemento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           @*<input style="width:270px;" type="text" id="complemento-input" name="complemento-input" placeholder="Complemento" class="form-control-sm">*@
       </div>

    <div class="offset-md-5" style="margin-left:261px;">
        <div class="col col-md-2">
           <label for="cpf-input" class=" form-control-label">CEP:</label>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.EndCep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "width:90px;", type = "text", id = "text-input", name = "text-input", placeholder = "Cep" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.EndCep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
             @*<input style="width:90px;" type="text" id="cep-input" name="cep-input" placeholder="Cep" class="form-control-sm">*@
          </div>
      </div>
```

Minha controller esta assim:

```
 public ActionResult Create(CadastrarColaboradorViewModel colaborador)
 {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Colaborador colab = new Colaborador();

                //Salva endereço do Colaborador
                using (var db = new Contexto())
                {

                    Endereco endereco = new Endereco
                    {

                        EndBairro = colaborador.Endereco.EndBairro,
                        EndCep = colaborador.Endereco.EndCep,
                        EndCidade = colaborador.Endereco.EndCidade,
                        EndComplemento = colaborador.Endereco.EndComplemento,
                        EndNumero = colaborador.Endereco.EndNumero,
                        EndRua = colaborador.Endereco.EndRua,
                        EndUf = colaborador.Endereco.EndUf
                    };
                    db.Endereco.Add(endereco);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    var idEndereco = endereco.IdEndereco;
                    colab.IdEndereco = idEndereco;
                }
                //Salva Endereço Fim *-*-*-*

                colab.Nome = colaborador.Nome;
                colab.Cpf = colaborador.Cpf;
                colab.DataDeNascimento = colaborador.DataDeNascimento;
                colab.Email = colaborador.Email;
                colab.EstadoCivil = colaborador.EstadoCivil;
                colab.Funcao = colaborador.Funcao;
                colab.Sexo = colaborador.Sexo;
                colab.StatusDoColaborador = colaborador.StatusDoColaborador;
                colab.TipoDeColaborador = colaborador.TipoDeColaborador;




                db.ColaboradorDb.Add(colab);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(colaborador);
        }
```

O problema é o seguinte, como eu to salvando o endereço e atribuindo o id salvo ao colaborador, o endereço salva corretamente, porém, em alguns casos da erro, ao salvar o colaborador, dai o endereço fica salvo sem um colaborador.

Gostaria de saber se existe um método onde eu possa validar se o colaborador foi salvo com sucesso, e se não foi, eu gostaria de deletar o endereço que eu ja salvei no banco.

Comment: Você pode usar um `try{}catch(Exception e){} ` para capturar e tratar esses erros...

Comment: Boa tarde. Há uma ferramenta chamada TransactionScope, onde se caso houver algum erro na aplicação, ela retorna os passos. Observe mais em [TransactionScope - Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.7.2) No seu caso creio que ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É importante você verificar o motivo dos *casos da erro*, pois de repende é um problema simples, como uma propriedade obrigatória que deveria ter sido preenchida para um determinado cenário, ou um campo preenchido com tamanho maior que configurado, por exemplo etc.

O problema do Endereço ficar salvo sem um Colaborador ocorre porque existem 2 transações:

- Uma salva o Endereço
- Outra salva o Colaborador

Pode ocorrer a situação onde uma delas da erro e a outra salva com sucesso. Existe mais de uma forma de resolver esse problema.

Acredito que usando `try/catch` não é a melhor forma: você poderia colocar um `try{...}catch{...}` na primeira transação e só realizar a segunda se a primeira dar certo. Porém essa solução não é ideal pois, o que fazer em casos que a primeira da certo mas justo a segunda transação dar errado? Não tem mais como dar rollback da primeira transação.

Outra solução é usando [UnitOfWork](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) (na internet tem vários exemplos de implementação), onde suas transações serão coordenadas e você vai executar um comando `SaveChanges` gravando todas operações uma única vez, caso alguma dê errado ocorre *rollback*.

Outra forma pode ser usando transações assim:

```
public ActionResult Create(CadastrarColaboradorViewModel colaborador)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {           
        try
        {
            Colaborador colab = new Colaborador();

            //Salva endereço do Colaborador
            using (var db = new Contexto())
            {
                // Cria o objeto para controlar a transação
                using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                        Endereco endereco = new Endereco
                        {

                            EndBairro = colaborador.Endereco.EndBairro,
                            EndCep = colaborador.Endereco.EndCep,
                            EndCidade = colaborador.Endereco.EndCidade,
                            EndComplemento = colaborador.Endereco.EndComplemento,
                            EndNumero = colaborador.Endereco.EndNumero,
                            EndRua = colaborador.Endereco.EndRua,
                            EndUf = colaborador.Endereco.EndUf
                        };

                        db.Endereco.Add(endereco);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        var idEndereco = endereco.IdEndereco;
                        colab.IdEndereco = idEndereco;

                        //Salva Endereço Fim *-*-*-*

                        colab.Nome = colaborador.Nome;
                        colab.Cpf = colaborador.Cpf;
                        colab.DataDeNascimento = colaborador.DataDeNascimento;
                        colab.Email = colaborador.Email;
                        colab.EstadoCivil = colaborador.EstadoCivil;
                        colab.Funcao = colaborador.Funcao;
                        colab.Sexo = colaborador.Sexo;
                        colab.StatusDoColaborador = colaborador.StatusDoColaborador;
                        colab.TipoDeColaborador = colaborador.TipoDeColaborador;    

                        db.ColaboradorDb.Add(colab);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                    // Só nessa linha tenta fazer commit das 2 transações
                    transaction.Commit();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");       
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Porém, se der erro faz rollback
                transaction.Rollback(); 
                return View(colaborador);
            }
        }    
    }
    return View(colaborador);
}
```